# Aspect Oriented Programming in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-aop, spring-annotations

Feb 28, 2012 12:46:54 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@780024: startup date [Tue Feb 28 12:46:54 GMT+05:30 2012]; root of context hierarchy
Feb 28, 2012 12:46:54 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [newSpringXMLConfig.xml]
Feb 28, 2012 12:46:55 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@ef98ac: defining beans [org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,tri,cir,shape,LAspect]; root of factory hierarchy
Feb 28, 2012 12:46:55 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@ef98ac: defining beans [org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,tri,cir,shape,LAspect]; root of factory hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tri' defined in class path resource [newSpringXMLConfig.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pointcut is not well-formed: expecting 'name pattern' at character position 4
get()
    ^

```
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at sam.mainaop.main(mainaop.java:16)
```

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pointcut is not well-formed: expecting 'name pattern' at character position 4
get()
    ^

```
at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.resolvePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:316)
at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:294)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:195)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.checkReadyToMatch(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:181)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getClassFilter(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:162)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:200)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:254)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:286)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:117)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:87)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:68)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:359)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1426)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
... 11 more
```

Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)

and the code:

```
package sam; 

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect; 
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before; 
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut; 

@Aspect public class LoggingAspect { 
  @Before("get()") 
  public void LoggingAdvice() { 
    System.out.println("Good Afternoon"); 
  } 

  @Before("get()") 
  public void LAdvice() { 
    System.out.println("Good Morning"); 
  } 

  @Pointcut("execution(* get*())") 
  public void get() { } 
}
```

Comment: The Below program is my aspect class
Cant guess the error....
Help me please...am new to Spring Aop
Thanks in advance...

Comment: package sam;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;


@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

    @Before("get()")
    public void LoggingAdvice() {
        System.out.println("Good Afternoon");

    }
    @Before("get()")
    public void LAdvice() {
        System.out.println("Good Morning");

    }
    @Pointcut("execution(* get*())")
    public void get()
    {
    }
}

Comment: Please edit the question adding the broken code and some details removing it from the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the [spring aop doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html)

The full AspectJ pointcut language supports additional pointcut designators that are not supported in Spring. These are: call, get, set, preinitialization, staticinitialization, initialization, handler, adviceexecution, withincode, cflow, cflowbelow, if, @this, and @withincode.

so I assume that you should avoid the naming confliction in Spring Aop